# Discord.net C# вопрос

Tags: c#, бот, discord

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое проиходит? Почему роль не упомянается должным образом?
Discord net v3.13.1

Edit: все права у бота есть(упомянание всех ролей - yes, application.commands(dev discord portal) - yes)

```
if (command.CommandName == "манга") 
    { 
            var embed = new EmbedBuilder() 
            .WithTitle(selectedTitle) 
            .WithDescription($"Том {selectedTom} Глава {selectedChapter} {is_extra}{is_end}{is_new}\r\n\r\n————————————\r\nНовая глава для манги ***«{selectedTitle}»*** была опубликована на <:mangalib:1215401143501328384> [**MangaLib**]({titleUrl})\r\n————————————\r\n\r\n<:mangalib:1215401143501328384> [**MangaLib**](ссылка1) | <:boosty:1215405767964889179> [**Boosty**](ссылка2)") 
            .WithFooter(new EmbedFooterBuilder() 
                .WithText($"Опубликовал {nickname}") 
                .WithIconUrl(avatarUrl)) 
            .WithCurrentTimestamp() 
            .WithColor(Color.Orange) 
            .WithImageUrl(imageUrl) 
            .Build(); 
            await command.RespondAsync($"<@&{roleId}>", embed: embed); 
    }
```

В чём может быть дело?

Дополню, что `{roleId}`, `{selectedTitle}` и т.д. - это переменные. Они применяют значение, которое пользователь укажет в команде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вопрос уже был задан: почему пинг приходит без упомянания? При этом если указать command.user.Mention, то пользователь будет упомянут. Но роль - он в никакую не хочет пинговать.

Как должно быть(как пинг от человека):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как происходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности, заоловок вопроса с текстом "вопрос" - это весьма малоинформативно.

Comment: Что происзодит? Как должно быть? О чём вопрос?

Comment: Вы ведь написали `$"<@&{roleId}>"` - то есть, вы знаете как "упоминать роль", если все другие "Такой хороший" - это роль, то я не вижу там аналогичного синтаксиса упоминания в коде, я вижу простое `selectedTitle`, `{selectedTitle}` и т.д.

Comment: Дополню, что {roleId}, {selectedTitle} и т.д. - это переменные. А вопрос уже был задан: почему пинг приходит без упомянания? При этом если указать `command.user.Mention`, то пользователь будет упомянут. **Но роль - он в никакую не хочет пинговать**.